# Giving a function for a $1-1$ function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory

Show that the given intervals have the same cardinality by giving a formula for a $1-1$ function, $f$, mapping the first interval onto the second.

$[1,3]$ and $[5,25]$

So I understand that I have to create a rule that works for all values in the interval but is there a way to do this besides guess and check?

I tried making an equation:
$x=5$ and $3x=25$ and solving but I realize the formula would be far more complicated then just multiplication. Can someone help me get this started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first interval length is $2$, the other one $20$. So you need to expand the values range by the coefficient $10$. However $f_0(x)=10x$ is not enough, as $f_0(1)=10$ instead of $5$. So you need to subtract $5$ from $f_0$ to get the desired result: $$f(x) = f_0(x)-5 = 10x - 5$$
You can easily test that $f(1)=5$ and $f(3)=25$, also that for every $1\le x\le3$ you get $5\le f(x)\le 25$.

Comment: perfect explanation! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
A linear polynomial is uniquely identified by its starting and endpoint (that is by two pairs $(x, f(x))$) and is continuous so it satisfies the IVT.

For a bijection $[a,b] \to [c,d]$ you can use
$$f(x) = c + \frac{d-c}{b-a} (x-a)$$

Comment: So I understand the starting point in both intervals are related and the endpoint in both intervals are related but how do I find the formula to represent them?

Comment: Use $f(x) = ax + b$ and solve for $a,b$ knowing $f(1) = 5$ and $f(3) = 25$.

Comment: how did you know to use  f(x)=ax+b?

Comment: Linear polynomials are precisely that.

Comment: yeah I understand that, but how did you know looking at the two intervals that it was in fact a linear polynomial?

Comment: and so for the first interval using f(1)=5 How do I find the values of a & b. So I have f(1)=a(1)+b then f(1)=3(1)+2 I figured the solutions by guess and check but i know those same values won't work for f(3)

Comment: @Lil That's a system of two linear equations with two variables. I trust you know how to solve these:
$$\pmatrix{1&1\\3&1} \pmatrix{a\\b} = \pmatrix{5\\25}$$